# SSRS - Why are PDF viewed results correct but browser results are not?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I'm using Report Builder 3.0 to develop a simple SSRS report calculating a percentage.

I have 3 columns, 2 not visible with data each contained in a column group, and 1 as a visual representation of the data displayed as a percentage. The 2 columns are grouped by the same SQL column value, but have different filters to separate the data. I need a percentage of column A compared to the total of column A + column B displayed in my third column, so I'm using the expression:

`=FormatPercent(ReportItems!columnA.Value/(ReportItems!columnA.value + ReportItems!columnB.value),1) & " whatever additional text"`

```
ColumnA                    ColumnB                    ColumnC
Group on IsWeb             Group on IsWeb             A/(A+B)
Filter IsWeb = 1           Filter IsWeb = 0
SUM(value)                 SUM(value)
```

This works fine unless column A doesn't actually contain any values. In other words, the filter on the column group for column A filters out any potential data. When this happens, `ReportItems!columnA.value` doesn't even exist, so I can't use an `IIF(IsNothing())` statement in the third column to replace it with 0.

What's odd is that when the report is run via the web interface, RB interface, or delivered in an HTML formatted email, the percentage returns as 50.0% when `columnA.value` doesn't exist. However if you save it as a PDF, it shows 0.0%, which is what's desired.

Is there a way to "fix" the issue of 50.0% appearing in the browser and email viewing of the report, or properly set the final calculation to insert 0 in place of the calculation when `ReportItems!columnA.value` does not exist?

I tried:

`IIF(IsNothing(ReportItems!columnA.value), 0.0, FormatPercent(ReportItems!columnA.Value/(ReportItems!columnA.value + ReportItems!columnB.value),1))`

but this also didn't work as intended.

To test the "0 divided by a number" problem of the data display, if I change the 3rd column's expression to:

`=FormatPercent(0/(ReportItems!columnA.value + ReportItems!columnB.value),1) & " whatever additional text"`

it functions as expected, returning a 0.0% result in the browser as well as by PDF.

EDIT: It appears that the value `ReportItems!columnA.value` is replaced with the value from `ReportItems!columnB.value` when it doesn't exist. Column B always has a value, so when we get to the final equation of A/(A+B), when A doesn't exist, the equation turns into B/(B+B), hence the 50.0% result. However when I export the results to PDF, A is simply 0 and B is the correct amount resulting in a correct display of data.

Why does the HTML viewing return different results than when exported to PDF?